# Is it appropriate to use a bootstrapped standard error in a meta-analysis?

Tags: bootstrap, meta-analysis

If the effect size under analysis is too complex to allow for any other type of standard error estimate, is it appropriate to use bootstrapped standard errors to inform effect size weights?

Comment: I do not understand what kind of association could be there in bootstrapping and effect-size weighing ? I wish you detail some ideas that pervade your mind and the method  of meta-analysis.

Comment: Effect-size weights may be calculated as a function of their (the effect size) standard error. Bootstrapping is one way of [estimating the standard error of an effect size](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Advantages).

Comment: Is it something-like inverse variance weighing and should I presume that standard error here is equivalent to what is termed as standard deviation?

Comment: would you please indicate the nature of effect-size as well as its generation through survey studies or controlled experiments